# Transient Behaviour of current source into capacitor + resistor

Tags: capacitor, transient

[image]

**Can someone please explain this transient behaviour circled - particularly the capacitor current?**

Capacitor has a relationship of I = C * dv/dt.
I know the AC current will split based on the impedance of C1 and R1 but that is for steady state right? Can someone explain to me slowly what exactly is happening in the transient phase circled in red?

I was trying to deduce the capacitor current by the dv/dt but I don't know the dv/dt. If I try and deduce the v(t) based on the cap current, I run into the issue of not knowing how much current flows into cap.

Comment: You have a PWL current source that ramps up, goes steady, then ramps up again for a shorter time, then goes steady. For the first ramp and knee, the response is the first exponential pulse, for the second you have the second exponential pulse, which is of a shorter duration, otherwise it would have looked like the first one. In other words, the second exp. pulse is the truncated version of the first one. BTW, using `V(N002)` is meaningless for anyone except you, since nobody can probe a picture -- add labels to mak life easier.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen good point, I updated the node name.

Comment: Why are you concerned about the circled area, but not the larger ramp immediately to the left?  What satisfies you about that region, but not this?  It's the same system, the system is linear, they represent identical behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You know that RC=T reaches 63.2% of the exponential target from (1-1/e).

Your target in the circle is an increase of 200 mA, but because that change is limited by the defined slope interval also happens to match the RC time constant the response in Ic is 1/2 of 63% or a peak of 63 mA.

- a similar answer can explain this with your equation Ic=CdV/dt plus include \$\Delta\$V=CdI/dt which is the increase in charge voltage over the interval.